# custom toggle button with image and text

Tags: android, layout, drawable, togglebutton

I want to create a toggle button with image on the left of the text. I use this code to make the image on the left:

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:textOn="Like"
            android:textOff="Liked"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tggle_btn_like"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
           />
```

However the image is too big. If I set the layout_width and layout_height to a value, the image doens't scale accordingly. My question is how to set with and height for the left drawable of a toggle.

[image]

I want to make it like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a padding

paddingRight or paddingLeft

```
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
```

Comment: That isn't what I want. I want to scale the image to a smaller size. However, android:layout_width and layout_height don't scale the left drawable.

Comment: which size did you apply to android:layout_width ?

Comment: I want to make it as smaller as the second image.

Comment: Because I want to use unit dp. If I edit it with photoshop. I can't use dp unit. Therefore, it will have a different size on different screen.